# How to connect to Oracle ODBC datasource using cx_Oracle Python?

Tags: python, oracle, odbc, datasource, cx-oracle

I need some help on how to connect to ODBC datasource using cx_Oracle in python.
In cx_Oracle we have feasibility to use Custom/User defined data types ie oracle objects and collection and calling procedure. So with with functionality Iam looking for ODBC data source connection also.

I got pyodbc module which connects to ODBC, but again their I am unable to handle with user defined data types and calling procedure.

Kindly help with suitable module which support oracle user defined datatypes(object/ collection), ODBC connection and procedure calling.

Comment: Your question is confused.  ODBC and cx_Oracle are APIs that allow connections to Oracle Database.  They are independent of each other.  If you want to work with Oracle DB user defined datatypes then you have to use cx_Oracle.

Comment: I want datasource connection and user defined datatypes of oracle both together.